# PowerButton interrupt unable to idle the screen

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing android game using andengine.
Only 1problem wat i am facing is after powerinterrupt my game will get pause(which is correct)
but my screen is not going to idle state. How to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

```
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"  to my activity in my manifest file solved my problem.